# How to stop scrolling on touchend with mobile safari?

Tags: javascript, touch, mobile-safari, hammer.js

I'm trying to get this kind of action on a web app, which consists of a "mosaic" of views, altogether 6 columns of views in 6 rows. The navigation works nicely on a desktop browser, but with Mobile Safari it gets difficult.

This is the action I'm trying to get:

> User swipes (quickly) -> page moves 1 view up/down/left/right 
>   User touches & drags -> page follows finger
>   User lifts finger (touchend) -> inertial scrolling stops, page moves 1 view up/down/left/right

Currently I'm using Hammer.js, which works great with its prevent_default -setting as true, but the content doesn't follow the finger while dragging.

Which is easier/better, moving the page on a drag-event with code, or trying to hijack the scrolling on touchend?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track! I love hammer.js. If you want the page to move with the users finger I would move the page on a drag event with code. For example you could do something like:

```
hammer.bind('drag', function(ev) {
    x = ev.position.x;
    y = ev.position.y;
    mosaic.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d('+(x) +'px, '+(y) + 'px, 1px)';
```

With "mosaic" being the container that holds the tiles. The tricky part is determining which image to then "snap" to. Perhaps you could also use jQuery .offset() to determine the relation between the touche coords and your mosaic?

Check out the latest edition of Hammer.js for some extra help. You may now also evaluate:

```
center      {Object}        center position of the touches. contains pageX and pageY
deltaTime   {Number}        the total time of the touches in the screen
deltaX      {Number}        the delta on x axis we haved moved
deltaY      {Number}        the delta on y axis we haved moved
velocityX   {Number}        the velocity on the x
velocityY   {Number}        the velocity on y
```